# Using a lambda value from function as first element of list

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp, lisp-2

I'm reading over Peter Norvig's Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming, and I've come across an issue I cannot resolve on my own (this is my introduction to Lisp). The issue is quite a small one, really, but obviously not one my little brain can solve.

Why is it that when a function's value is a lambda, it is an error to use that function as the first element to a list. For example:

Lisp:

```
(defun some-func ()
  #'(lambda (x) x))

;; At REPL
;; Does not work
> ((some-func) 1)
;; Does work
> ((lambda (x) x) 1)
;; Also works
> (funcall (some-func) 1)
```

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good question, and one where Common Lisp can be pretty confusing.  The thing is that due to historical reasons, Common Lisp has two namespaces -- one for functions and another for values.  To make this happen, there are two different evaluation rules for the head position of a function application and for the rest -- the first will evaluate a symbol as a function name, and the second will evaluate a symbol as a variable reference.  There are obviously cases when the value is actually a function -- for example, if you write a `mapcar` function, you'll want to do something like

```
(defun my-mapcar (f l)
  (if (null l)
    '()
    (cons (f (car l)) (my-mapcar f (cdr l)))))
```

but this won't work -- it will complain about `f` being an unknown function.  For these cases there is a special function called `funcall`, which receives a function and argument for the function, and will apply the function as usual -- and since `funcall` is a plain function, its arguments are all evaluated as usual (as values).  So the above should be fixed by using it:

```
(defun my-mapcar (f l)
  (if (null l)
    '()
    (cons (funcall f (car l)) (my-mapcar f (cdr l)))))
```

As you probably suspect now, there are the mirror cases -- where you want to evaluate something as a function and *not* as a value.  For example, this doesn't work:

```
(my-mapcar 1+ '(1 2 3))
```

because it refers to the `1+` variable and not the function.  For these cases there is a special form called `function` that evaluates its contents as a function and returns it as a value:

```
(my-mapcar (function 1+) '(1 2 3))
```

and it can be abbreviated with `#'`:

```
(my-mapcar #'1+ '(1 2 3))
```

That's not the end of this story -- to give a few examples:

- in some cases a simple quoted name can work as a function -- for example `'1+` in the last example works -- but this is a kind of a hack that can see only globally bound names, so `#'` is almost always better
- a similar hack can be used with `lambda` -- so you can use `(my-mapcar '(lambda (x) (1+ x)) '(1 2 3))`, in fact, you could use `(list 'lambda '(x) '(1+ x))` which is even worse (and IIRC, non-portable), but using `(lambda (x) (1+ x))` works since it's implicitly wrapped in a `#'` (try expanding a `lambda` form as a macro and you'll see it).  A related hack makes it fine to use a `lambda` expression as the head of a function application (which is one of the things you've tried).
- `let` etc bind local values, and in some cases you'll want to bind local functions instead -- for this, there are new binding constructs: `flet` and `labels`

If all of this looks weird and/or overly complicated, then you're not alone.  It's one of the main differences between Common Lisp and Scheme.  (The difference then leads to changes in common idioms in both languages: Scheme code tends to use higher order functions much more frequently than Common Lisp code.  As usual with these kind of religious questions, some people argue in favor of what CL does, claiming that higher order functions are confusing so they like the explicit in-code reminder.)

Comment: Thanks, Eli, for taking the time to write this; it has helped a bunch! I can't upvote you right now, but when I can - I will. Again, thanks.

Comment: I find the separation of function and variable namespaces very useful, and I frequently create and use higher-order functions.

Comment: quote lambda does not work in Common Lisp. (my-mapcar '(lambda (x) ...) ...) is not Common Lisp and will generate an error. Consing it as a list will also not work in Common Lisp. I would also guess that Common Lisp uses at least as much higher order functions as Scheme. For example several functions take functions like KEY and TEST as arguments, where Scheme provided multiple versions for EQ, EQL and EQUAL.

Comment: Svante: Yes, I did say that the preference is a religious one.  As for any anecdotal comparison between how many HO functions you use vs anyone else -- that's exactly the kind of "discussion" that leads nowhere.  My "tends to" is obviously subjective too; it is based exactly on the fact that CLers often claim that they prefer the explicit distinction.  It's clear to me how you'd proceed to counter that and since it is subjective, so be it.  The main point (which will become stronger) is that this is first and foremost a religious issue.

Comment: Rainer: You're right -- I should have clarified that "IIRC, non-portable" applies to both forms of a quoted lambda expression that precede that.  (And BTW, that worked for me in Allegro, and (as expected) it doesn't work in CLISP.)  (And BTW#2, I considered mentioning newLISP as an interesting experiment in promoting it to a fundamental feature, but that's probably diverging too far.)

Answer (score 4):

`((lambda (x) ...) ...)` is a hardcoded special case in the evaluator rules. It's not evaluating the first element in the form and using the result as a general case. It's normal that you have to use `funcall` or `apply` to call a function that is the result of evaluating some other form.

Comment: Right, I believe this is what is described by CLHS 3.1.2.1.2.4 (!!): "A lambda form is equivalent to using funcall of a lexical closure of the lambda expression on the given arguments."  http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababd.htm

Answer (score 2):

**The reason Common Lisp doesn't allow a function that returns a lambda to be the first item in an expression has to do with the distinction between [Lisp-1 and Lisp-2](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Technical-Issues.html).**

If Common Lisp allowed `((some-func) 1)` to be equivalent to `(funcall (some-func) 1)`, then it could be perceived as inconsistent to not also allow say `(let ((f #'some-func)) (f 1))` rather than require `(funcall f 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very good justification for not supporting such forms: They are ambiguous.  Consider the way [function names](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_name) are defined in Common Lisp:

> **function name** *n*. 1. (in an *environment*) A *symbol* or a *list* `(setf symbol)` that is the *name* of a *function* in that *environment*. 2. A *symbol* or a *list* `(setf symbol)`.

Given this, how should a form like the following behave?

```
((setf car) 10 x)
```

Should this set `x`'s car to the value `10`, or should it execute the form `(setf car)` (which would be an error) and try to use its return value as a function to call with the arguments `10` and `x`?  Common Lisp specifies neither behavior, and it's not at all clear to me that that's a bad choice.  After all, as far as I can see, nothing in the standard prevents conforming implementations from extending the definition of valid forms to support a wider range of operator names (so special-casing setf-functions wouldn't really help here, either).

Comment: Interesting. I would expect the inner-form to be executed and the value of that to be used as the function (or function-name - I'm still a little confused as to the difference between the two and where the two are used). However, I would be wrong, of course, as proved by this thread! Heh. I guess it makes sense when you consider the evaluation rules; still, it's a little confusing at first (and maybe for a little while thereafter).